# VS Test Explorer. vs 2017 Get a list of selected tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vstest

How can I use the Visual Studio TestWindow/TestPlatform interfaces, or any available, in a custom visual studio plugin to get the current list of selected tests in the Test Explorer?

Preferably get a list of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility.ITest objects.

Edit:
I do see in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller a class called DiscoverySelectedOperation. Can this class be utilized?

Comment: Maybe you can check [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/writing-a-visual-studio-2012-unit-test-adapter/).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't actually deal with getting a list of selected tests from the test explorer.

Comment: Do your extension only targets VS2017, since VS2019 will remove some test-related apis, including the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility.ITest. See [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1830).

Comment: A yes, the object Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestCase  will also do the right job.